# Is this finite difference approach correct?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, iterative-method, navier-stokes

I am solving incompressible 2D Navier-Stokes equations with zero y-component velocity. The geometry is a simple 2D pipe of a length $L$ and diameter $W$ and there is only two boundary conditions:

1. Non-slip on the pipe walls: $u = 0$
2. Flow velocity at inlet $u = U_{max}$

and so, the two equations I have are:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$
$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$$

using finite difference discretization I came up with the following:

1.continuity equation:
 $$ u_{i,j} = u_{i+1,j} $$
2. Pressure using forward difference:
$$P_{i,j} = P_{i+1,j} - \frac{\mu \triangle x}{(\triangle y) ^2}(u_{i,j+1} + u_{i,j-1} - 2u_{i,j})$$
3. Pressure using backward difference:
$$P_{i,j} = P_{i-1,j} + \frac{\mu \triangle x}{(\triangle y) ^2}(u_{i,j+1} + u_{i,j-1} - 2u_{i,j})$$
4. Manipulating equation (2) to get an equation for $u$:
$$u_{i,j} = \frac{u_{i,j+1}}{2} + \frac{u_{i,j-1}}{2} - (\frac{P_{i+1,j} - P_{i,j}}{\frac{2\mu \triangle x}{(\triangle y) ^2}}) $$

I shall then use Gauss–Seidel method to solve the previous equations, but since I made two finite difference equation for u and P using the same partial differential equation I can't tell whether this is correct or not as I am getting very weird results.

So, is my approach correct?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense.  You seem to be missing an equation.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I have another equation: $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$$ But I don't think adding it to the system of equation is going to make any difference, or is it?

Comment: @Algo, You are right, you do not need the extra pressure equation since you are resolving the continuity equation which implicitly is an equation for pressure. 
It looks like you are using a collocated grid which is prone to an oscillatory pressure distribution and an unrealistic velocity field. This can be remedied using a staggered grid for the pressure and velocity variables.

Comment: As @namu said, your considering the momentum equation, with the continuity constraint (for incompressible flow). You also must specify boundary conditions, this is important and missing from your question.

Comment: Also, you cannot say you're solving a 2D NS equation with one of the remaining components of velocity being zero, this is 1D NS.

Comment: @Charlie I added more details about the geometry and B.C.s, and the 2D analysis is meant for getting the velocity profile over the length L (however it might be constant for fully developed flow) and the pressure gradient over the length.

Comment: @namu so is the problem with my FDE formulation (or iteration method?) or it's that I am using a collocated grid?

Comment: @Algo, you can properly solve NS on a collocated grid, you just have to be careful. Also, is this flow through a cylindrical pipe or flow in a 2D box? Can you clearly describe the problem? Also, you are missing a boundary condition at the outlet.

Comment: @Charlie, you can have 2D NS with the velocity in the y-direction being zero. Consider the problem of plane shear flow.

Comment: @namu, I agree that such a flow only has one component, but this is the result of specific initial and boundary conditions and does not imply that the other components are not solved for. In addition, assuming a single component flow implies that the flow is stable (laminar).

Comment: @namu, it seems that you may be confused about what you're trying to model. I imagine you're thinking of one of 3 situations. 1) Fully developed pipe flow - 1 axial cell - only 1 velocity component 2) Fully developed pipe flow - many axial cells - only 1 velocity component - requires the correct ICs and BCs (fully developed pipe flow inlet AND outlet) 3) Developing pipe flow - many axial cells - must have > 1 components (to enforce continuity at entrance) - permits uniform inlet flow, or fully developed inlet and outlet (which might simplify to case 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question I think.

1) Do your equations match the physical problem you're trying to model?

2) Do your finite difference equations converge to the continuous ones as dx and dt approach zero?

First, I'd like to address question 1, since this affects question 2.

**Question 1**: Assuming you're looking for a general (developing) flow solution, this image is a helpful illustration:

[image]

As you can see, the entrance region (ER) extends to a critical point where the flow reaches a fully developed (FD) state. In the FD region, there's only 1 non-zero component of velocity, however, in ER there are multiple components.

The governing equation (for the entire domain) are momentum and continuity:

$\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \bullet \nabla \mathbf{u} = - \nabla p + \frac{1}{Re} \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}$

$\nabla \bullet \mathbf{u} = 0$

According to [here](http://ingforum.haninge.kth.se/armin/AR_2000/HL2008/NAVIER_STOKES_EQ.pdf), this simplifies to (assuming $u_{\theta} = 0, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} = 0$, which also implies that we're assuming a laminar solution)

r:
$\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial t} + u_r \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} + u_z \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{Re} \left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} \right) - \frac{u_r}{r^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u_r}{\partial z^2} \right]$

z:
$
\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t} + u_r \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} + u_z \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}
=
-\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} + \frac{1}{Re}
\left[ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} \right)
+ \frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial z^2}
\right]
$

Continuity:
$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial (r u_r)}{\partial r} +\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} = 0$

With this, we may apply general inlet BCs as you suggested:

$u_r = u_{r,inlet}(r,0)$

$u_z = u_{z,inlet}(r,0)$

Likely outlet BCs might be

$u_r = 0 $ (more fewer unknowns than $\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} = 0$)

$\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} = 0$

**Question 2**: Since there are many different approaches to solve equations in question 1, I will just briefly comment on some approaches rather than writing finite difference equations.

You may discretize in space and time and then apply a solution method (you suggested Gauss-Seidel). You may use staggered variables, where velocity and pressure are located on the cell face and center respectively, or you may use a collocated scheme, but then you will need to compute fluxes for the advection term in order to avoid pressure checkerboard phenomena. Typically, 2nd-order central difference schemes are applied to these equations for spatial derivatives, unless higher order discretization is needed. Since it seems you've written your equations for steady state, I'll assume that you're not interested in transient behavior and suggest using 1st-order (explicit Euler) time marching.